# ifstream not working in Code::Blocks debug mode

Tags: c++, codeblocks

First Some Code:

```
std::ifstream resolution;
resolution.open("resolution.txt");
if(resolution.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Open";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not Open";
}
```

This program works (prints "open" and can read from file) when I build and then run from the windows explorer folder but when I press the run button in code blocks or try to use the debugger it prints "not open" and crashes when I try to read from the file.

I have found that SOIL (the OpenGL utility) cannot read files when run from within code blocks

How do I enable file loading when debugging?

Comment: The current working directory is most likely different if you run the program in a development environment. Try using a full path name for the file. Some development environments also have settings where you can specify the current working directory.

Comment: @RetoKoradi OMG Thank you I can finally use the debugger. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change the working Director for the debug executable.